# Angular run after complete

Tags: angularjs, promise

I am new to Angular, so this will be easy to most.
I have a service with one function:

```
.factory('HttpHandler', function () {
    return {
        loadData: function (promise) {
            var self = {
                data: [],
                loading: true,
                promise: promise
            };

            promise.then(function (data) {
                self.data = data;
                self.loading = false;
            });

            promise.finally(function () {
                self.loading = false;
            });

            return self;
        }
    };
});
```

What I would like, is to be able to run something else after this has completed successfully. Seudo code:

```
var result = httpHandler.loadData(httpCall, function (complete) {
    console.log('this has completed');
});
```

Can someone explain to me how I can do this?

Comment: I wonder what you need this `self` object for at all. It seems to do not much more than the promise alone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without changing your `httpHandler`, this is the closest you can get to the behavior you describe in your code:

```
var resultPromise = httpHandler.loadData(httpCall)
                      .promise
                      .then(function (complete) {
                          console.log('this has completed.')
                      });
```

However, you probably want to save the result of `httpHandler.loadData(httpCall)` separately to use the other properties from therein:

```
var result = httpHandler.loadData(httpCall);
result.promise.then(function () {
    console.log('this has completed: ', result.loading, 
                ' with data: ', result.data);
});
```

Comment: I knew it was simple :)